# What is the behavior WM_CLOSE and WM_QUIT messages in VB6?

Tags: windows, vb6

If I execute them in one application to close another appliation, do this messages activate Unload Form inside the code in VB6?

Thank you.

Comment: Make a quick test and try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WM_CLOSE asks the window to close.  Most apps will exit after closing its main window.

WM_QUIT tells the window to quit the current message loop.  If that's the main message loop, most apps will then exit.  If it's a message loop for a modal dialog, the dialog will likely close and the app will likely continue to run.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I thought I'd get an answer faster.

1. WM_CLOSE (not recognized by VB6 - You have to specify a value of &H10 or Decimal 16) does in fact execute the Unload code in the MDI form of the application)
2. WM_QUIT is akin to terminating process, it does not call that code.